# Laravel - Query "with"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-3, laravel-relations

I have a query where I need to get info from 2 tables. So I need to get invoices with the `invoice_status` 1, where the `user_status` is 1.
I though I could query the Invoices table with the users table. When I `dd($invoices)` I do get the invoice with the users just fine...

```
$invoices = Invoice::with('user')->where('invoice_status', '=', 2)->get();
```

But I'm not sure sure how I can get the `users->account_statu`. I tried this but get a query error it can not find account_status.

```
$invoices = Invoice::with('user')->where('invoice_status', '=', 2)->where('account_status', '=', 1)->get();
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass in a closure to handle the query for the eager-loaded content:

```
$invoices = Invoice::with(array('user' => function($query) {
    $query->where('account_status', '=', 1);
}))->where('invoice_status', '=', 2)->get();
```

Comment: This is not working for me, I'm getting a syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Comment: Probably because of the new array syntax. See my edited answer